# Detect other blog posts on the Internet similar to my posts

Tags: tools, blog

Others can modify or copy and paste my articles and put it in their blogs without any link to me.

Is there any way to recognize or track my copied content? Are there any tools on the Internet that could help or do it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of paid and free tools which will help to identify sites/pages which have similar content. For example [copyscape](http://www.copyscape.com/) or plagium are two such offerings.

Overall however your best bet is to make sure that you are seen as the original author/source of the content. A well constructed and well liked/linked site can help to establish this.

This is a huge topic however and there is a whole spam industry dedicated to stealing peoples content and repackaging it to gain traffic for ads. StackExchange has a long history of fighting this.

Answer (score 2):

You may use copyscape to track your content, not only blogs but also other publications and websites, is largelly used by teachers and copywriters

[www.copyscape.com](http://www.copyscape.com)

Answer (score 1):

For Wordpress try [this](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/how-to-find-similar-blogs), whereas Blogspot has a widget [here](http://widgetsforfree.blogspot.in/2009/01/related-posts-widget-for-blogger.html).